# Opencart2.0.2.0 footer.tpl is not changing anymore, how can i edit?

Tags: footer, frontend, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.0.2.0 and i want to add some social media icons on footer so that i am trying for 1 hour but no any effects.

```
here is my footer.tpl code

<hr>
<p><?php echo $powered; ?></p>
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Instagram</li>
</ul>
```

which is not displaying on my footer page.

[image]

Comment: You have to clear the modification cache to update the system and make the changes work. You can clear  by top right buttons on Extension > Modification page in admin panel. then check it.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i'm have the same problema, my solution:
1.- make a copy of you footer.tpl, rename them foother.tpl on

```
/catalog/view/theme/you_theme/template/common
```

for example no_footer.tpl

2.- the system use the footer.tpl in theme/default, remplate this

```
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl
```

for you new vercio, and its all :)

some mods make a copy of you footer (and other tinks), this copy can be reset by use the admin tool ( enter to you_page/admin, go to Modifications and use the orange icon "clear" ) this reset a lot of files to the original forma + mods changes, manual changes can be lost (make a backup if you use a lot of changes nod made by mods)

if you like to change this files manual, you can go to

```
/system/modification/catalog/view/theme/theme547/template/common
```

and change the footer.tpl, this file is create or update when you make a reset on the files